# Jquery Mobile non-adjustable width

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile, responsive-design, fluid-layout

Using asp.net `<EditItemTemplate>` my JQuery Mobile results are a fixed width and will not expand out with full browser, nor will they reduce small enough for mobile? I have removed all reference to `width` in all the controls?

The controls render as mobile and the `<ul>` and `<li>` look fine.

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="ul-edit-picks" data-divider-theme="a" data-inset="true">
            <li>1st Week:
                <asp:TextBox ID="CHOICE1TextBox" runat="server" Text='1st Week' ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox><br /> 
                <asp:HiddenField ID="CHOICE1HiddenField" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("CHOICE1")%>' />
            </li> 

            <li>2nd Week:
                <asp:TextBox ID="CHOICE2TextBox" runat="server" Text='' ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox><br /> 
                <asp:HiddenField ID="CHOICE2HiddenField" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("CHOICE2")%>' />
            </li>

            <li>3rd Week:
                <asp:TextBox ID="CHOICE3TextBox" runat="server" Text='' ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox><br /> 
                <asp:HiddenField ID="CHOICE3HiddenField" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("CHOICE3")%>' />
            </li>

            <li>
                <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"
                    Text="Update Selections" ToolTip="Click to change your selections..."></asp:Button> 
                <asp:Button ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
                    Text="Cancel"></asp:Button>
            </li>
</ul>
```

HTML rendered:

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="ul-fdid" data-divider-theme="a" data-inset="true">
            <li>FDID:
                <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_Label1" style="font-size:Medium;font-weight:bold;">BJ9150</span>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul data-role="listview" id="ul-edit-picks" data-divider-theme="a" data-inset="true">
            <li>1st Week:
                <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FormView1$CHOICE1TextBox" type="text" value="1st Week" readonly="readonly" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_CHOICE1TextBox" /><br /> 
                <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FormView1$CHOICE1HiddenField" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_CHOICE1HiddenField" value="1/19/2014 12:00:00 AM" />
            </li> 

            <li>2nd Week:
                <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FormView1$CHOICE2TextBox" type="text" readonly="readonly" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_CHOICE2TextBox" /><br /> 
                <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FormView1$CHOICE2HiddenField" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_CHOICE2HiddenField" value="4/13/2014 12:00:00 AM" />
            </li>

            <li>3rd Week:
                <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FormView1$CHOICE3TextBox" type="text" readonly="readonly" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_CHOICE3TextBox" /><br /> 
                <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FormView1$CHOICE3HiddenField" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_CHOICE3HiddenField" />
            </li>

            <li>4th Week:
                <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FormView1$CHOICE4TextBox" type="text" readonly="readonly" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_CHOICE4TextBox" /><br /> 
                <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FormView1$CHOICE4HiddenField" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_CHOICE4HiddenField" />
            </li>

            <li>5th Week:
                <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FormView1$CHOICE5TextBox" type="text" readonly="readonly" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_CHOICE5TextBox" /><br /> 
                <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FormView1$CHOICE5HiddenField" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_CHOICE5HiddenField" />
            </li>

            <li>6th Week:
                <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FormView1$CHOICE6TextBox" type="text" readonly="readonly" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_CHOICE6TextBox" /><br /> 
                <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FormView1$CHOICE6HiddenField" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_CHOICE6HiddenField" />
            </li>

            <li>
                <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FormView1$UpdateButton" value="Update Selections" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_UpdateButton" title="Click to change your selections..." /> 
                <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FormView1$UpdateCancelButton" value="Cancel" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_UpdateCancelButton" />
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: What does the final html of the asp:TextBox render to?

Comment: updated: question to include rendered output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually solved the issue: It was a `<asp:label>` lower in the code that produced text that was not set to wrap.

Comment: Actually ... the `<ul>` is not expanding to the full width of the browser as well?