# JQuery Mobile <ul> not expanding in full browser

Tags: jquery-mobile

Using a basic `<ul>` and `<li>` within asp.net project with input controls, can't figure out why `<ul>` will not expand to full browser width? The `<ul>` will expand with wider `<li>` content.

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="ul-edit-picks" data-divider-theme="a" data-inset="true" data-scroll="true">
            <li data-role="list-divider">
                <h2 id="itemTitle">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FDID")%>' Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
                : Selections</h2>
            </li>

            <li>1st Week:
                <asp:TextBox ID="CHOICE1TextBox" runat="server" Text='1st Week' ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox><br /> 
                <asp:HiddenField ID="CHOICE1HiddenField" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("CHOICE1")%>' />
            </li> 

            <li>2nd Week:
                <asp:TextBox ID="CHOICE2TextBox" runat="server" Text='' ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox><br /> 
                <asp:HiddenField ID="CHOICE2HiddenField" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("CHOICE2")%>' />
            </li>

...

            <li>
                <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"
                    Text="Update Selections" ToolTip="Click to change your selections..."></asp:Button> 
                <asp:Button ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
                    Text="Cancel"></asp:Button>
            </li>
</ul>
```

Screen Shots:

[image: reduced] 
[image: expanded]

Comment: What is the paretn element of the UL? What is its rendered HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Try with  data-inset="false" on < ul >

Comment: then you have some issue with css, play a bit in firebug with css

Comment: can you give page content HTML, you have to much padding there

Comment: See other post with HTML output: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645334/jquery-mobile-non-adjustable-width   this is using standard jquery mobile 1.4.3

Answer (score 0):

ok the problem was in the `<FormView>` of the .net section of my page, see: [asp.net formview generates table at fixed width 259px](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25653563/asp-net-formview-generates-table-at-fixed-width-259px/25654267#25654267)

it's seems the default width of 259px is auto generated in the form based on content size.