# asp.net formview generates table at fixed width 259px

Tags: asp.net

Dynamically generated table in FromView is causing problem in my JQuery Mobile page. I have narrowed it down to the table that is generated is fixed at a width of 259px with an ID of `table#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1`

I'm not sure how to change this to dynamic in asp.net FromView:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="FDID" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DefaultMode="Insert">                  
    <EditItemTemplate>        
        <ul data-role="listview" id="ul-edit-picks" data-divider-theme="a" data-inset="true" data-scroll="true">
            <li data-role="list-divider">
                <h2 id="itemTitle">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FDID")%>' Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
                : Selections</h2>
            </li>

...
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make the table dynamically resize as the window resizes?

Comment: yes - my `<ul>` would not expand to full width and I determined it wasn't the `<ul>` it was the FormView `<table>`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old post - you can just not generate the formview inside a table

`asp:FormView ID="MyFormView" **RenderOuterTable="false"`

Answer (score 0):

ok not sure why the `<FormView>` defaulted to 259px but the fix was to add `Width="100%"` to the control, I have never had this issue in the past, but I guess I just liked the default look.